# I m using tkinter to read an excel file using 1 button.

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Generally a file has 20k rows and 45 columns. So this takes few seconds and freezes the GUI. How to avoid this? it's just 2 lines of code. How to stop freezing of tkinter GUI? How will you use threading in such a small function?

Comment: Try "lazily loading" the content: only fetch and display part of it at a time. Please also post your code.

Comment: Lazy loading is ideal as already stated. Using a separate thread to load would be another viable option and be simpler to implement, though not as efficient.